# How do I efficiently output to a non-contiguous range in Google Apps Script (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Script, so appreciate your help!

Here's what my data looks like (3 non-contiguous records, 4 non-contiguous fields):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18FFB2HlcfcciHj7NPmihZbuf47op2UMdRTKfpyTqowU/edit#gid=0

I have an array of the items and each item is an object that contains 4 keys.  I want to output to Google Sheets in as few SetValue requests as possible.  If I can't do it in 1 call, then it makes most logical sense to output each item at a time.

My idea is that I can create ranges for fields 1 and 4 that span the entire column. Then I can create ranges that span the entire Item row. Then the INTERSECTION between the 2 is the range I want to output to, once I have assembled an array of 2 values.

Or perhaps since assuming I know the rows/columns of each cell below, I can return the range and the use a UNION of the ranges to create the mapping instead.

But is there a function to do Intersection or Union in GAS?  Or am I better off just outputting each cell 1 by 1?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: GAS uses JavaScript.  Whatever JavaScript can do with arrays and objects, GAS can do.  The `SpreadsheetApp` service reads and writes data with 2 dimensional arrays.  All you need to do, is have blank elements in the inner array for cells that you want to leave blank.  Or, you can get all the original data, then just inject the changes you want to the 2D array, and write it back to the spreadsheet.  So, the write to the spreadsheet can be done in one call using that strategy.

Comment: What if the cells in the middle are not blank and are actually links/formulas?

Comment: That might be a problem.  Maybe you could write some code and test it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such function. It's either one by one or contiguous cells.

But there's quite a few tricks/alternatives that might work for you. As Sandy pointed in a comment, you could get a contiguous range that had all required cells and set the non-required ones to blank or their original values. This has the down side of not working for formulas.

You could also pre-configured the required cells with simple formulas "pointing" to a continuous range. That would simply bulk update at once.

If bulk setting is really required, you could also grab all values ***and*** formulas of the wide range, and convert all plain values to their equivalent formulas, e.g. `abc` becomes `="abc"` and `1/1/2015` `=DATE(2015,1,1)` (yes, it's cumbersome) and then use setFormulas to set everything back, both original formulas and values converted to formulas. Making no actual content change in the cells you don't want to and changing the required ones, all in one bulk operation.

Anyway, these are just workarounds. As stated in the first sentence, it's not possible, period. You probably want to star [this report](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=456) in Apps Script issue tracker to kind of vote for this feature and receive updates.

Comment: There *is* such a function, using the [Advanced Sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910373/is-there-a-way-i-can-update-multiple-non-contiguous-google-sheet-ranges-using-ap).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but today, there is a more elegant solution using `RangeList`.

You can select a list of `Range`, add these `Range` to a `RangeList`, and perform a single operation on it.

This example demonstrates how to apply changes to cells `D4` and `E6` in a single operation, even though the cells are not contiguous.

```
var rangeList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeList(['D4', 'E6']);
rangeList.setBackgroundColor('blue')
```

You can find more details about the `RangeList` class in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list?hl=en).